# event for the closingof the browser

Tags: asp.net

i am having a asp.net and c#.net application and i have a page gridview.aspx which has a button "close".

when a person closes the browser page by clicking the close icon in the top right of the browser i want to perform the click event of the "close" button,

do we have any event beforebrowserclose()?

Comment: i am clearing off the session values while clicking the close button,if iam clicking the browser close evnt it is not clearing the session vlues,so i want to clear thesession values also in the browser close event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function clickclosebtn() {

```
        if (window.event.clientX < 0 || window.event.clientY < 0) 
    {

        document.getElementById("<%= btnClose.ClientID %>").click(); 
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

WebForms applications use PostBacks to fire off Events. Since the browser doesn't do a PostBack before it closes, there's no way to wire an Event for that.

Unfortunately there's not even a reliable, cross-browser way to accomplish this in Javascript either.